# How can I make this query return the latest record from the audit table (MSSQL 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have looked at a few SO answers regarding this, but since I am not really even close to an amateur DBA they were a little over my head. Talking about cte's and some built in functions that I have never seen before. I am wondering if there is a simpler solution to what I am trying to find. Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT systudent.lastname, 
                systudent.firstname, 
                ...
                systatchange.effectivedate AS StatusChangeDate 
FROM   systudent 
       INNER JOIN systatchange 
               ON systudent.systudentid = systatchange.systudentid 
       INNER JOIN syschoolstatus 
               ON systudent.syschoolstatusid = syschoolstatus.syschoolstatusid 
       INNER JOIN amleadsrc 
               ON systudent.amleadsrcid = amleadsrc.amleadsrcid 
       INNER JOIN amleadtype 
               ON systudent.amleadtypeid = amleadtype.amleadtypeid 
       INNER JOIN sycountry 
               ON systudent.sycountryid = sycountry.sycountryid 
       INNER JOIN adprogram 
               ON systudent.adprogramid = adprogram.adprogramid 
WHERE  systatchange.effectivedate >= Dateadd(day, -7, Getdate()) 
       AND systatchange.newsyschoolstatusid = 1 --Lead 
       AND syschoolstatus.descrip NOT IN ( 
           '56-Future Graduate', '92-Application Denied' ) 
       AND amleadtype.code <= 'HS2014' 
ORDER  BY leaddate DESC
```

I am gathering information on people who within the last two weeks have had a status change  to '1' (SyStatChange.NewSySchoolStatusID).

The problem I am running into is that for some users the status change audit table is showing duplicate records. They all have the correct status change fields, but the effective dates are milliseconds to minutes off, so I am getting dupes. So for user 1 2 and 3, I would want only the most recent record from each one.

What is the *easiest* way to only get the SyStatChange info on the record(s) with the most recent date change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function is probably the *easiest* way.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    --note that you shouldn't use DISTINCT
    SELECT systudent.lastname, 
           systudent.firstname, 
           ...
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY systudent.systudentid 
                              ORDER BY systatchange.effectivedate DESC
                             ) as RN
           --Partition by on whatever is your unique/id column (or columns)
    FROM ... --your tables
    WHERE ... --your conditions
    --no order here
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY leaddate DESC
```

PS: Please, try using aliases for your tables instead of full names. It will make your queries much more readable.

Comment: Dude, thanks! works like a charm. I am adding PARTITION and CTE on my list of things to research more. Also, I am back and forth on table aliases. For this particular query it is on a giant 3rd party db, so the full table name helps me keep track of where exactly I am pulling the data. On DBs I create and maintain I usually use aliases. Thanks again!